# How to arrange multiple android fragments with nested FrameLayouts?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'd like to display a simple landscape layout with one list fragment on the left half of the screen and two vertically aligned fragments on the right. Showing all three fragments horizontally works fine, but my layout below shows only the list fragment and not the two others inside the vertical LinearLayout on the right. What am I doing wrong with my layout parameters?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment class="com.copperykeenclaws.gameplanner.TeamListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/team_list_fragment"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </fragment>
   <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/team_details_frame" 
                android:layout_width="0px" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/team_players_frame" 
                android:layout_width="0px" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The FrameLayouts get replaced programmatically in FragmentTransactions, which works fine in the all-horizontal layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `team_details_frame` and `team_players_frame` have widths of 0px, so they'll won't show. Either give them a layout_weight attribute (although nested layout_weights are discouraged, I doubt there will be much of a performance hit in your case) or set them to wrap_content or match_parent.

Comment: You're on the right track, but it's a vertical layout.  Set the widths to match_parent and the heights to 0px, then give them some weight.